# SKNode 'Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled' Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This part of my code is outdated and it gives errors and errors.

Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

```
   extension SKNode {
        class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
            if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
                let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
                let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

                archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
                let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
                archiver.finishDecoding()
                return scene
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
```

My first code was:

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you what yo need to do; `NSData(contentsOfFile:)` can throw if the file can't be read. You either need to wrap this in a do/try/catch and handle the error or indicate that this function throws and handle the error where you call it. Essentially Swift no longer allows you to ignore error handling as you did in your original code (it doesn't force you to handle it correctly but you do need to at least consider errors by writing a catch clause)

Comment: I tried it, but it never ends with errors. Can you send me a code example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my working fix!**

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {

            do  {
            let sceneData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()

            return scene

            } catch {

            }

        } else {
            return nil
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still ignoring errors.  If you are going to do that you should probably just use `try!` so that you get a runtime exception in the case of file not found; This will at least point you at the problem during debugging rather than leaving you with an empty scene

Answer (score 0):

Functions that return an NSError have changed to throw an Error in Swift 2. The message you are getting indicates that your code calls a function (specifically the NSData initialiser) that can throw, but you aren't handling this and you haven't indicated that your function can throw; you have to do one or the other.

Since your function returns an optional I would suggest that you mark that it throws change it to return a non-optional. You will need to handle the error in the caller with a do/try/catch.

```
enum MyAppError: ErrorType {
   case fileNotFound
}

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) throws -> SKNode {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped)
            let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            throw MyAppError.fileNotFound
        }
    }
}
```